# To say thanks to Stack Overflow for this site

Tags: support

Thank you Stack Overflow, I am sincerely saying this, I have had a lot of queries and complex questions solved. Actually I'd not know how to show gratitude and how to send a message, so I added this.

Thanks,
Anudeep